cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
So everytime I attempt to "process" a save file it spits:
>  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\source\BBSaveEditorFix\app.py", line 291, in _process_data_user
    self.data, self.user = process_user(self.file_location)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object

Here's the code for line 291:
    def _load_all_gems(self):
        if self.gems is None:
            messagebox.showwarning("File not loaded!", "You can not reset all modifications since no file is loaded")
            return
        self.combobox_all_gems['values'] = [list(gem.get_original_stats())[0] for gem in self.gems]

    def _set_original_gem_stats(self, e=None):
        if e is not None:
            for gem in self.gems:
                if list(gem.get_original_stats())[0] == e.widget.get():
                    self.selected_gem = gem
        for i, (gem_menu, value) in enumerate(zip(self.all_gem_menu, list(self.selected_gem.get_original_stats()))):
            if i > 2:
                gem_menu.set(value)
            else:
                gem_menu.config(state="normal")
                gem_menu.delete(0, END)
                gem_menu.insert(INSERT, value)
                gem_menu.config(state="disabled")

    def _process_data_user(self):
        if self.file_location is None:
            messagebox.showwarning("User not loaded!", "No file selected")
        self.data, self.user = process_user(self.file_location)
        self._set_original_users_stats()

    def _process_data_gems(self):
        if self.file_location is None:
            messagebox.showwarning("File not loaded!", "No file selected")
        self.data, self.gems = process_gems(self.file_location)
        self._load_all_gems()

    def _open_file_selection(self):
        self.file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="./")
        self.file_loc_ent.config(state="normal")
        self.file_loc_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.file_loc_ent.insert(INSERT, self.file_location)
        self.file_loc_ent.config(state="disabled")

Here's the process_user code:
def proecess_user(filename: str):
    data = None
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    hexdata = binascii.hexlify(data)
    if not data.startswith(b"41000000000000"):
        return False
    return data, extract_user_info(data) 


def process_gems(filename: str):
    data = None
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
    data = binascii.hexlify(data)
    if not data.startswith(b"41000000000000"):
        return False
    return data, extract_gems(data)


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question. What do you need help with exactly? Like to start, do you understand what the error means? Check out [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify.

BTW: 1) you have a typo: *proecess. 2) hexdata is never used. 3) data = None is not necessary.

Also, for debugging help, please make a [mre] and provide the full error message with traceback.

You can't unpack to two variables when process_user() returns False

This expects the function to return a sequence of two values:
self.data, self.user = process_user(self.file_location)

But the function can possibly return a single value:
if not data.startswith(b"41000000000000"):
    return False

... which causes the error.

Could you give an example of how this could be implemented?

@noob Either change the call to not expect a sequence of two values, or change the function to always return a sequence of two values.

I changed it to this:
def _process_data_user(self):         if self.file_location is None:             messagebox.showwarning("User not loaded!", "No file selected")         self.user = extract_user_info(self.file_location)         self.data = process_user(self.file_location)         self._set_original_users_stats()

yeah - you could return None, None or similar, but I'd be most tempted to do some raise ValueError and let the caller handle it
